# Blazor app not redirecting to identity server from custom layout

Tags: c#, authentication, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm using .NET 6 Blazor WASM. When I enter the app, I am navigated to the "LoginLayout", as expected, because I am unauthenticated.
However, when I press the "Login" button in that layout, nothing happens, although the url has changed to "localhost:xxxxx/authentication/login". I expect to be redirected to my central authentication server page.

Why is this happening? Can anyone help? Thanks for your time!

**App.razor**

```
<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <Authorizing>
                    <p class="lead">Please wait...</p>
                </Authorizing>
                <NotAuthorized>
                    @if (context.User.Identity?.IsAuthenticated != true)
                    {
                        <RedirectToLogin />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p class="lead">Not allowed to view that page.</p>
                    }
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
            <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p class="lead">Nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>        
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

**RedirectToLogin.razor**

```
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager

@code {
    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo($"authentication/login?returnUrl={Uri.EscapeDataString(_navigationManager.Uri)}");
    }
}
```

**MainLayout.razor**

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<AuthorizeView>
    <Authorized>
        <AppLayout Body=@Body />            
    </Authorized>
    <NotAuthorized>
        <LoginLayout />
    </NotAuthorized>
</AuthorizeView>
```

**LoginLayout.razor**

```
@inject IConfiguration _config
@inject NavigationManager _navigationManager
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

// code omitted
<div class="login-page-main d-flex justify-content-center">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="OnLoginBtnClicked">Login</button>
</div>

@code {
    private void OnLoginBtnClicked()
    {
        _navigationManager.NavigateTo($"authentication/login");
    }
}
```

**AppLayout.razor**

```
// only for authenticated users.
@inherits LayoutComponentBase
<div>
   // code omitted
   @Body
</div>
```

**Authentication.razor**

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@attribute [AllowAnonymous]

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@code{
    [Parameter] public string? Action { get; set; }
}
```

I have added in **_Imports.razor** the following line:

```
@attribute [Authorize]
```

The only info message I receive in console is the following:

> info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
> Authorization failed. These requirements were not met:
> DenyAnonymousAuthorizationRequirement: Requires an authenticated user.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a component that handles authentication/login?

**Authentication.razor** looks like this by default:

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@code{
    [Parameter] public string? Action { get; set; }
}
```

You may have to tweak it to use a layout that does not require authentication E.g.

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@layout LoginLayout
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication
@inject NavigationManager Navigation

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@code{
   [Parameter] public string? Action { get; set; }

   protected override void OnParametersSet()
   {
       if (new string[] {"logged-out", "logout-callback"}.Contains(Action))
       {
           Navigation.NavigateTo("/login");
       }
   }
}
```

**LoginLayour.razor** should have no authorization. E.g.

```
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<div class="page">
    <main>
        <article class="content px-4">
            @Body
        </article>
    </main>
</div>
```